# How can I use useFormikContext hook in my class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, formik

I'm working with Formik forms in React Native App. I want my form to be submitted using a button that is outside the Formik component. I know how the useFormikContext hook works but the problem is with my component which is a class component (not a functional component). How can I submit my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've to use React.createRef() in order to solve my problem.
I've created the ref in the constructor like this

```
this.myRef = React.createRef();
```

then I've to apply innerRef prop to my form like this

```
innerRef={this.myRef}
```

and finally I've to call submitForm method in my handleSubmit like this

```
this.myRef.current?.submitForm();
```

That's it :)